# Question about the proof of the maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and connected and $f$ be
>   holomorphic in  $G$. If $|f|$ has a local maximum in some point $z_0
>  \in G$, then $f$ is constant on $G$.

*Proof.* Let $U \subseteq G$ be a neighbourhood of $z_0$ (according to the terminology in the book not necessarily open, it just contains an open ball around $z_0$) such that $$|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$$ holds for any $z \in U$. Then we have that $$f(U) \subseteq \overline{B}_{|f(z_0)|}(0)$$ Now  $f(U)$ is not a neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$. The author wants to apply the following theorem:

> Let $f$ be a nonconstant holomorphic function on an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Then also the image of this subset is open and connected.

Now the author concludes from the above, that $f(z) \equiv f(z_0)$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. **Why is this so?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ contains a connected open neighbourhood $V$ of $z_0$. If $f\lvert_V$ were not constant, then $f(V)$ would be open, and in particular a neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$. Thus $f\lvert_V$ is constant, and by the identity theorem, $f$ is constant on $G$.

Answer (score 2):

The key ingredient is the following

**Fact:** Let $w\in\mathbb{C}$, and let $V\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open neighborhood of $w$. Then there is a $w'\in V$ with $|w'|>|w|.$

If $F$ attains a maximum at $z$, it follows from the above fact that the image of $f$ does not contain an open neighborhood of $f(z)$. It now follows from the open map theorem (highlighted in your post) that $f$ is constant.